# PDF images included in a PDF document with XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdftex, pdf, viewers

I am writing a presentation in Beamer, and I am compiling using XeLaTeX. Some PDF images I include in my presentation have a weird behaviour: they show up correctly in Mac OS's Preview application, however they don't display on Adobe Reader.

Is there a way of solving this problem? Researching for a solution I saw that people solved this by forcing a specific PDF version. However I am not able to do that in XeLaTeX.

Actually I don't need the images to be included as vectorial graphics, a method to tell LaTeX to include them as raster would also be perfect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quickest fix is then: Reader -> File -> Export… and render it as a .png file or similar. For more thorough problem solving, can you provide a pdf file where that error appears?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I found a solution which I posted below, it was some obscure incompatibility due to the fact that Mac OS X Quartz PDFContext apparently generates non-standard-compliant PDF files... Please see below if you are curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was quite obscure, but maybe some will find it useful, so I am writing it here.

The .pdf images I was including were generated by an application which is using the default Mac OS PDF engine. Apparently it is generating non-compliant PDF 1.7 files. At least that's Ghostscript output when I try to process those PDFs:

```
**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by:
**** >>>> Mac OS X 10.11.6 Quartz PDFContext <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.
```

The solution is: converting the PDF images to PDF 1.4 using the following command line

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -o output.pdf input.pdf
```

Then ignore Ghostscript error message, and finally use the new "normalized" PDF 1.4 files in your LaTeX document.