# One figure can't be insseted by "xelatex" but can be by "lualatex" or "pdflatex"

Tags: graphics, xetex, includegraphics

I have a pdf file which contains a figure in it. I can insert it by `LuaLaTeX` or `pdfLaTeX`, but can't be inserted by `XeLaTeX`. What is the reason?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[]{1.pdf}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The error in `XeLaTeX` is

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "./1.pdf" (page=0).

Just download the file and you can duplicate this error.

[The download address](https://bthc-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/mr_iem_im/Ees1qLkTBTxPpB8y3ucJygsBggJqJUQR1jCo_AB0XCSUhQ?e=BhbrdI)

Comment: your links asks for a password, I won't do that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thanks for your kind reply. I updated it now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it doesn't now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can download it in the incognito window of Chrome. It is weird.

Comment: @Y.zeng the download worked for me, I assumed you had changed the settings after Ulrike said it required a password, did you not? There is something weird about that pdf:-)

Comment: my pdfsyntax checker reports errors in this file and xdvipdfmx complains: xdvipdfmx:warning: Cannot parse cross-reference stream.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Error while parsing PDF file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  The first link is from personal Onedrive. I even don't know how to set password. And the second is from Business Onedrive.

Comment: After seeing @DavidCarlisle response below: Do you have Linux or other system with command line (BASH) ? If so, install program `qpdf`. It can inspect a PDF file and report file errors. My guess is that 1,pdf has a non-fatal internal syntax error, ignored some software but not by other software.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be syntax errors in the original pdf that prevent xdvipdmx from reading the file, but if you do

```
pdf2ps 1.pdf
mv 1.ps 1b.ps
ps2pdf 1b.ps
```

so that ghostscript re-writes the pdf, and change the tex to include `1b.pdf` instead, it runs without error in xelatex and produces

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `xelatex` engine?

Comment: @Y.zeng yes the above output is xelatex

Comment: @Y.zeng I got the error that you showed with the original 1.pdf

Comment: What is the reason? Solving problems is good, finding problems is good. I want to know why an error is reported.

Comment: @Y.zeng sorry a pdf file is a binary file, if its internal structure is incorrect then you can't just look at it and see what is wrong. ghostscript is quite good at correcting minor errors on input, and if it can read it, it almost always writes corrrect pdf. So I can't tell you what is wrong (Ulrike found a tool to give some error message, in the comments under the question). All I can tell you is that ghostscript silently corrects it on reading the file.

Comment: xetex is less forgiving with invalid pdf than pdftex and luatex are. This kind of issue pops up every once in a while, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196644/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374488/82917

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Okay. Thanks a lot. At least I knew why I can't know the error deeply.

Comment: @campa  The pdf format is perfect as it can't be find the error in it and even it has an error, the Adobe wouldn't show any information about it.